# Get collection with changed one field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a problem with getting a collection array with changed one field in each document. 
My document is:

```
{postId: "123123", author: "someId"}
```

And I want to search by author id in other collection and replace author with author name instead of id
Is there any simple way to do that?

EDIT:
I've wrote something like this

```
  {
      $lookup: {
        as: "USER",
        foreignField: "created",
        from: "Users",
        localField: "userName"
      }
    }
```

Then i recive array of documents from Users collections. I wan't only one based on the value from the field of collection posts

**EDIT:**
Sample documents from collections:

**POSTS:**

```
{
  _id: 'p7c3d',
  author: 'p9jhkl',
  content: "Hello",
  createdAt: '12-12-2019',
  tags: ['hello'];
}
```

**USERS:**

```
{
  _id: 'p9jhkl',
  name: 'John Smith'
}
```

And I wan't that "John Smith" to be in post author field instead of user id.

**Edit:**
Picture of actual documents

[image]

Comment: To be clear, you want to run an update on the users collection updating **all** the users by replacing the author field with the matching name from the authors collection?

Comment: No, not update i wan't to make a find on collection Posts replacing all createdBy values with userName values from users collection;

Comment: @KacperŁukasik : Can you please show us the sample documents in your both collections, From your explanation & your query it's still hard to understand what's happening, Please do edit your question..

Comment: I've updated the question with example documents

Comment: @KacperŁukasik : So you wanted to update value of `author` field in POSTS collection with value of `name` field (instead of _id) in USERS collection across all documents in POSTS collection ?

Comment: Yes, but no update, just recive changed collection with find method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is only 1-to-1 relation i.e; documents in POSTS can have only one matching document in USERS.

**POSTS :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "p7c3d",
    "author" : "p9jhkl",
    "content" : "Hello",
    "tags" : [ 
        "hello"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "p7c3d11",
    "author" : "p9jhkl11",
    "content" : "Hello",
    "tags" : [ 
        "hello"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "p7c3d1122",
    "author" : "p9jhkl1122",
    "content" : "Hello",
    "tags" : [ 
        "hello"
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "p7c3d No",
    "author" : "p9jhkl No",
    "content" : "Hello",
    "tags" : [ 
        "hello"
    ]
}
```

**USERS :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "p9jhkl",
    "name" : "John Smith"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "p9jhkl11",
    "name" : "John Smith11"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "p9jhkl1122",
    "name" : "John Smith1122"
}
```

Please try this :

```
db.POSTS.aggregate([{
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "USERS",
         localField: "author",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "userDetails"
       }
    },{$addFields : {author: { $arrayElemAt: [ '$userDetails.name', 0 ] }}},
    {$project : { userDetails: 0}}])
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "p7c3d",
    "author" : "John Smith",
    "content" : "Hello",
    "tags" : [ 
        "hello"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "p7c3d11",
    "author" : "John Smith11",
    "content" : "Hello",
    "tags" : [ 
        "hello"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "p7c3d1122",
    "author" : "John Smith1122",
    "content" : "Hello",
    "tags" : [ 
        "hello"
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "p7c3d No",
    "content" : "Hello",
    "tags" : [ 
        "hello"
    ]
}
```

Above query would completely remove the field `author` from documents of POSTS collection where there is no match with USERS documents (this would help to quickly remove POSTS docs from final o/p which has no match with USERS using `{$match : {author: {$exists : true}}}`), Just in case you need all documents from POSTS as is irrespective of whether there is a match or not, Check document 4 in results for clarification, Please try this :

```
db.POSTS.aggregate([{
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "USERS",
         localField: "author",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "userDetails"
       }
    },{$addFields : 
        {author: {
                 $cond: { if: { $ne: [ "$userDetails", [] ] },
                 then : { $arrayElemAt: [ '$userDetails.name', 0 ] },
                 else : '$author'}}}}, {$project : { userDetails: 0}}])
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "p7c3d",
    "author" : "John Smith",
    "content" : "Hello",
    "tags" : [ 
        "hello"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "p7c3d11",
    "author" : "John Smith11",
    "content" : "Hello",
    "tags" : [ 
        "hello"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "p7c3d1122",
    "author" : "John Smith1122",
    "content" : "Hello",
    "tags" : [ 
        "hello"
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "p7c3d No",
    "author" : "p9jhkl No",
    "content" : "Hello",
    "tags" : [ 
        "hello"
    ]
}
```

**With actual data :**

```
db.POSTS.aggregate([{ $addFields: { "createdBy": { "$toObjectId": "$createdBy" } } }, {
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "USERS",
        localField: "createdBy",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "userDetails"
    }
}, {
    $addFields:
    {
        createdBy: {
            $cond: {
                if: { $ne: ["$userDetails", []] },
                then: { $arrayElemAt: ['$userDetails.name', 0] },
                else: { "$toString": "$createdBy" }
            }
        }
    }
}, { $project: { userDetails: 0 } }])
```

Comment: Is there a typo in this second query with conditions? Because node throws an error

Comment: MongoError: Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.

Comment: Ok, what is the mongoDB version ?

Comment: it's version 3.3.4 in package.json

Comment: The typo was my fault the query works, but it's still gives me id instead of name in posts list.

Comment: @KacperŁukasik : Can you check if there is any data mismatch !! Or update this query with appropriate field names from your actual collection !!

Comment: I've updated question with screens of example documents from database. Only difference is that instead of author in database there is createdBy field, but I change it in your query and it still don't work.

Comment: @KacperŁukasik : So the doc above line is from USERS & below is from POSTS ? where do you've author field ? Do you want name to be in a new field ? Also createdBy in POSTS should match with _id in USERS ?

Comment: Yes and I wan't USER.name to be in POST.createdBy. Yes the id should match! There's no author field, createdBy is author field.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in three stages:

1. Match the author in posts to only get posts for an author
2. Join to authors using the created field
3. Project the fields you want, and only include the author's name in the result.

**Example Below:**

```
db.getCollection("posts").aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                created: ObjectId("5dd446cf3ccb4305e7fbec96")
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {from: "authors",
                let: { id: "$created" },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr:
                                {
                                    $eq: ["$$id","$_id"] }
                        }

                    },
                    { $project: { _id: 0, name: 1 } },
                ],
                as: "author"
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                author: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$author.name", 0]
                }
            }
        },

    ]
);
```